# Create reactive selectInput - flexdashboard with Shiny in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

i'm using shiney for the first time. I want to create a reactive widget containing the names of the cities of interest for my study. When selecting cities, the rendered graph must change.

This is my imported csv:

````
```{r}
    Data20 = read_delim("SAC55.csv", delim = ",")
    tail(Data20)
```
   `DIAS `    `SANTOAMARO ` ` CACHOEIRA ` `CDA ` `SAUBARA `   SFC
  <date>             <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-08-10           690           333    466         47   668
2 2020-08-11           695           335    470         47   676
3 2020-08-12           717           350    483         48   687
4 2020-08-13           719           356    500         48   701
5 2020-08-14           736           370    507         49   708
6 2020-08-15           763           377    527         49   713


```{r}
colnames(Data20) <- gsub(" ","",colnames(Data20))

```
DIAS       SANTOAMARO CACHOEIRA   CDA SAUBARA   SFC
  <date>          <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-08-10        690       333   466      47   668
2 2020-08-11        695       335   470      47   676
3 2020-08-12        717       350   483      48   687
4 2020-08-13        719       356   500      48   701
5 2020-08-14        736       370   507      49   708
6 2020-08-15        763       377   527      49   713
````

that's the way i'm trying to create a reactive selectImput

````
Data20 = read_delim("SAC55.csv", delim = ",")
colnames(Data20) <- gsub(" ","",colnames(Data20))
Data20$DIAS = as.Date(Data20$DIAS)



  ```{r}

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
selectInput(inputId = "Cidades", 
              label = "Cidades",
             choices = c("Santo Amaro" = "SANTOAMARO", "Cachoeira" = "CACHOEIRA", "Cruz das Almas" = "CDA", "Saubara" = "SAUBARA", "SFC" = "SFC"), 
             selected = "SANTOAMARO")),

mainPanel(plotlyOutput("city")))

  ))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  II <- reactive({
    Data20[ , c("DIAS", input$Cidades)]
     })

output$city = renderPlotly({
   ggplotly(ggplot(data = II(), mapping = aes_string("DIAS", y = input$cidades),  group=1))+
  geom_line(size = 1, col="pink")+
  geom_point(size = 1, col="red" )+
  labs(x = "DIAS") + 
  labs(y = "CASOS")+
  scale_x_date(NULL, date_labels = "%d, %b", date_breaks = "3 days")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 800), breaks = c(0,10,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,180,160,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380,400,420,440,460,480,500,520,540,560,580,600,620,640,660,680,700,720,740,760,780,800,900))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(text=element_text(family=" Arial ", size=9, face="bold"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family="Arial", face="bold", size=10, angle=45)) 
 })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```
````

Although the widget with the names of the cities appear the graphics are formed. I've tried several ways to resolve this to no avail.
If anyone can help me I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felipe - looks like there may be a few things going on here.

If your `II()` `reactive` expression is to pull the date and city data from `Data20`, then you may want (note the hard brackets):

```
Data20[ , c("DIAS", input$Cidades)]
```

otherwise, it will think `Data20` is a function.

Also, the sample data `Data20` has column names such as "SAUBARA", but the `selectInput` choices refer to `SAUBARA ` (with back ticks and a space) - these need to be the same.

Finally, in `ggplotly`, if you want the y-axis to display the selected city, then you could try:

`aes_string(x = "DIAS", y = input$Cidades, group = 1)`

...and `ggplotly` should be called on a `ggplot` object.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "Cidades", 
                  label = "Cidades:",
                  choices = c("Santo Amaro" = "SANTOAMARO", "Cachoeira" = "CACHOEIRA", "Cruz das Almas" = "CDA", "Saubara" = "SAUBARA", "SFC" = "SFC"), 
                  selected = "SANTOAMARO")),
    
    mainPanel(plotlyOutput("city")))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  II <- reactive({ 
    Data20[ , c("DIAS", input$Cidades)]
  })
  
  output$city = renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(ggplot(data = II(), mapping = aes_string(x = "DIAS", y = input$Cidades, group = 1)) +
      geom_line(size = 1, col="pink")+
      geom_point(size = 1, col="red" )+
      labs(x = "DIAS",  tail(129)) + 
      labs(y = "CASOS")+
      scale_x_date(NULL, date_labels = "%d, %b", date_breaks = "3 days")+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 800), breaks = c(0,10,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,180,160,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380,400,420,440,460,480,500,520,540,560,580,600,620,640,660,680,700,720,740,760,780,800,900))+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      theme(text=element_text(family=" Arial ", size=9, face="bold"))+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family="Arial", face="bold", size=10, angle=45)))
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for responding. I wish my reactive expression of Date20 city and date.
I made the suggested corrections however the graphics are not rendered and the following error message appears: _Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5530
Error in : Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `DIAS` and `SANTOAMARO` don't exist._

Comment: I’m thinking that’s because your csv file gives you different column names than the ones in your example above. The column names need to match your data. After reading in your csv file would make sure your column names have no spaces. Did you try my answer with your test data above to see if it works?

Comment: After your line of code with `read_delim`, you can remove all of the training spaces in the column names with: `colnames(Data20) <- gsub(" ","",colnames(Data20))` ... then, you don't need the back ticks and spaces with your column names. Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve it, even applying the corrections. This time there was a new error: Error in aes_string: argument is missing, with no default [No stack trace available]

Comment: Did you try my example code using the example data you provided, and not from your csv file? When I used your example data and the code I posted in the answer, it worked fine.

Comment: yes i tried it, both ways and both there is: Error in aes_string: argument is missing, with no default [No stack trace available]. 
I really don't know why it doesn't work here.

Comment: my only other thought is if you could edit your question and copy/paste exactly what you have for `Data20` and the code you are using, so I can try to reproduce the same problem...

Comment: hello Ben, I edited my question and inserted the content of my CSV, I hope that now it is easier to understand. Thank you.

Comment: I noticed 2 things - (1) this is using `aes` and not `aes_string` - and the column names are strings here. (2) the y axis is cases (CASOS) in yours, but there is no column named "CASOS" in the data set...

Comment: It was a mistake in the reissue, sorry for that. I will rewrite the code and study some commands and use their answers to find a way. thank you.

Comment: Please feel free to add any comments/questions later on - happy to help any way I can.